# How can I regex match which finds only nested pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace all the %(<>). String can be nested pattern as well.

```
para %(test) pattern %(te%(value)st) Hello Testing
```

I want it to be converted to

```
para MATCHFOUND pattern MATCHFOUND Hello Testing
```

Using the below regex

```
\%\((.*?)\)+
```

I get:

```
**para MATCHFOUND pattern MATCHFOUND*st)* Hello Testing**
```

Which is not correct as `st)` is not treated in pattern

Can anyone help me out with a proper regex to handle this.

Comment: For nested regex patterns see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns

Comment: Do you need balanced parenthesis? Also, is '2' the max amount of nesting? Or there's no limit?

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me: `/\%\([\w\%\(\)]*\)/g`

---

```js
var string = "para %(test) pattern %(te%(value)st) Hello Testing"
var regex = /%\([\w%()]*\)/g
console.log(string.replace(regex, "MATCHFOUND"));
// "para MATCHFOUND pattern MATCHFOUND Hello Testing"
```

Comment: no need to escape `%` here, and no need to escape `(` and `)` inside `[]`, so `/%\([\w%()]*\)/g` is enough

Comment: That's right! Thank you for the comment, I will update the answer :)

Comment: That will also match things like `para %(w)(a)` or `%((((aaa)`